# C# Console Application | Moving a character

Tags: c#, key, console-application, move

First of all, I'd like to apologize since this was probably asked before me. However, no matter where I looked, I just could'nt find the answer.
I want to make a certain character move ( constantly, or by a certain key ). 
By moving i mean it changing its position on screen. I dont think i really got the idea of it, but i think you can just use a for loop and add a space before this character everytime. If possible I would like to know how to make this for loop.
For example:
When you run the program, you see this:
*
And then after you press a key or just constantly ( as I mentioned before ):
 *
As you can see, the character moved right. But i want to know how to make it move to all directions ( up, down, etc.)

Comment: For some reason the website did not include the spaces in my example, so you cant really tell the diffrence. The point is, it moved right.

Comment: If you use the code format you can show spaces really well. Code format is started by using 4 blank spaces.

Comment: @ItayHabani why don't you post your code in question here..? let us see what it is you are attempting to do..

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8874/is-it-possible-to-send-characters-through-serial-to-go-up-a-line-on-the-console

Comment: @Amasa I'm pretty sure that had nothing to do with this

Comment: Look into [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll also need some kind of loop and [`Console.KeyAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable(v=vs.110).aspx), then [`Console.ReadKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx) if its true. You can see how I did this for a Nibbles clone I was working on here: https://github.com/ingeniousllc/Nibbles/blob/master/Nibbles/Level.cs

Comment: Highlight your code and press the toolbar button that looks like `{ }` to format the code if it does not show up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is good enough. Run the code, and press the arrow keys to move the asterisk around. Got inspiration from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const char toWrite = '*'; // Character to write on-screen.

        int x = 0, y = 0; // Contains current cursor position.

        Write(toWrite); // Write the character on the default location (0,0).

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                var command = Console.ReadKey().Key;

                switch (command)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        y++;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        if (y > 0)
                        {
                            y--;
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        if (x > 0)
                        {
                            x--;
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        x++;
                        break;
                }

                Write(toWrite, x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Write(char toWrite, int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) // 0-based
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                Console.Write(toWrite);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to `Thread.Sleep` some period inside the loop to keep the program from pegging out a processor.

Comment: Thanks, but its not that helpful... Im learning c# at my school, and this is my first year, so I dont really know what try, catch and some of those expressions mean... Today at class a friend show me how he did it, and he just used a for loop inside a foor loop. the outer one for the '*', and the inner one, for the spaces before the '*'. Can you show me a smiliar version to what he did please?